Why was the short field takeoff procedure changed from 1978 (flaps UP) to 1979 (flaps 10°) on the Cessna 172?
The Cessna 172N was produced for model year 1977 to 1980 (according to wikipedia). The first two years the short field standard procedure (i.e. "the checklist") says to set flaps up (or 0°), but last two years the standard procedure was changed to flaps 10°.
Why the change in the short field procedure? Particularly interested in any differences in aircraft / airframe design which may have led to this change, but whatever the reason I am curious.
See images below for screenshots from all four years' operating manuals, as well as the amplified procedures from 1977.
Additional info:

The 1979 model is also the first year where the first notch (that is, 10°) of flaps were permitted up to 110 KIAS.
1977 and 1978 models do not prohibit 10° flaps on takeoff. The earlier models explain in the operating manual's amplified procedures that 10° flaps results in shorter ground roll, but also shallows the climb angle. Therefore, you will have a longer distance to clear a 50 ft obstacle (see last image). Nonetheless, the standard procedure is flaps 0° for those two years.
The 1979 operator's manual contradicts its own standard procedure in the amplified procedure. The checklist has "Wing flaps -- 10°" but the amplified procedure says "Normal and short field takeoffs are performed with flaps up"...
I'm still confirming this, but I believe every model before 1977 used flaps UP for short field takeoff, and every model after 1980 used flaps 10° for short field. The exception is the retractable gear 172 which use flaps UP for all years (again - still going through all the old POHs I can find online to confirm this).
1977 saw a +10 horsepower gain over the 1976 172M model (thanks JohnK).

1977 POH (pg 4-8 / pdf pg 48)

1978 POH (pg 4-8 / pdf pg 28)

1979 POH (pg 4-8 / pdf pg 66)

1980 POH (pg 4-8 / pdf pg 54)

1977 "Amplified Procedure" (pg 4-14 / pdf pg 54)


Was this change for the new model - i.e. were the manuals for older models amended, or did the change just apply to new models?

This is an interesting question. The only change I can think of that would significantly affect takeoff and climb performance is the leading edge droop cuff added to the wing, in 1973 or 74 IIRC, and the change to 160hp in the N model in '77. The engine adopted in '77 was a famous debacle, with the oddly predictive model suffix "H2AD".

@DJClayworth I'm not sure where to look up amendments to aircraft manuals. The only place I know to look is the 172 TCDS (type certificate data sheet) - and I can't find anything regarding short field takeoffs in there.

@JohnK Regarding the 160 hp engine you mentioned: Could it have taken the engineers 2 years to realize the impact on short field performance? I every model before the 'N' used flaps UP, and every model after the 'N' uses 10° flaps for short field. The exception is the retracts (RGs). The RGs using flaps UP for short field may be even more evidence pointing to the engine being the main factor: the RGs are heavier and therefore the +10 hp may not have been enough to benefit from increased flaps.

You could have something were testing results in an update and change to the original performance data, but it would be strange to limit it to certain years unless there was some other configuration change.  Could the change in flap selector to the preselect do it? I think that was introduced in '79. A change from needing to hold the lever to just flipping it could have changed the approach to takeoff profile. Possibly.

One possibility is that during additional flight testing between 1978 and 1979, test pilots found that they saw a decrease in takeoff run distances or best angle of climb for obstacle clearance using 10° of flap as opposed to with flaps up and it was incorporated into flight manuals for the next iterations of the aircraft.

From doing a bit of digging on this, I think you'll find the answer not in the procedures, but in the performance charts. Compare the speeds and distances over a 50ft obstacle in both models with and without flaps.

I cannot find any indication there is a contradiction in the POH statements regarding the take-off procedure being questioned.

@ThomasPerry in the 1979 PDF, compare the short field procedure on page 4-8 (flaps 10°) to the amplified procedure on page 4-14 (short field takeoffs are performed with flaps up).

@codenoob  Ah, yes.  Ok, I think I see your question.  This is apparent traced back to 1956!  Still checking the details, but this is 'live' in the 172S POH.  Evidently this is guidance to inform choices at the pilot's discretion.  As this is mentioned in an advisory manner, the intent of Cessna may have been to preclude adverse consequences arising from any carelessness, incapacity, or neglect.

I think you indirectly answered your question by including the amplified procedure section from the 1977 manual.  Cessna appears to give conflicting instructions on how to perform a short field takeoff. I suspect that they were getting customer feedback concerning the clarity of operating procedures, and then made the changes for the 1979 manual to reflect a uniform procedure.

Personally, I'm more inclined to believe the extra 10 hp was the factor, and perhaps the test pilots didn't register the impact till '79 as you mentioned in your comment above. But these are all just opinions!

@codenoob perhaps more hp changed the best excess thrust curve to a slightly lower airspeed with flaps.   Keep in mind the prop pitch may also figure significantly as thrust = engine power × efficiency.  (Procedures may vary between  climb prop and cruise prop).  A strong clue is the passage:  advantage of flaps is lost in "high altitude takeoffs in hot weather at maximum weight" -  1977 amplified.

@codenoob There is no evidence that the increase in horsepower had anything to do with the amplified procedure.  There does not appear to be an issue here.  Apparently, Cessna changed nothing in the procedures being documented that are later identified as Amplified Procedures...

@ThomasPerry I think you are misunderstanding my question. In the procedure checklist (not the amplified procedure) the short field was flaps 0° from inception to 1978, and flaps 10° from 1979 to present. Why was the procedure (the checlist - NOT the amplified procedure) changed between those years? The business about the amplified procedure can be ignored - I was just pointing it out in case it was in any way a clue to the answer.


...10 degrees of flaps shortens the ground roll, but shallows the climb angle

This seems to be a mirror image of aircraft gliding performance, where lift to drag ratio is highest when the aircraft is "clean".
Flaps are useful in short/soft field takeoffs because they enhance ground effect.
An expert pilot will takeoff with flaps, raise them as the aircraft accelerates, and climb.
A less experienced pilot may run into trouble transitioning out of ground effect with insufficient airspeed.
But more horsepower is very useful for STOL because it allows higher coefficient of lift even if lift to drag ratio is lower$^1$.
This aircraft, similar in weight to the 172, used 240 hp, slats, and flaps to gain legendary short field performance.
$^1$ excess thrust determines maximum angle of climb

All very interesting, as usual from your answers. But alas, again as usual, it's hard to pinpoint the actual answer to the question posed. "Why was the short field takeoff procedure changed from 1978 (flaps UP) to 1979 (flaps 10°) on the Cessna 172?"

Robert, your answer has no downvotes. I refrained from that to give you time to fix your answer to be an answer. Sidenote: I fly 172's very regularly ;) I'm very interested in the answer to this one, hence my interest.

Thanks for being the first to take a crack at the question, but I was really interested in why the procedure changed in the manual between those specific years. As far as "need to know", well, let's just say I "want to know".

OK, ok.  It would probably be liability issues as more and more people with less experience got into flying.  Did not Cessna halt production for a number of years for the very same reason?

This post does not attempt to answer the stated question.

@RalphJ  because of issues such as weather and weight there may not be one correct answer.  More opinions may be found here

@RobertDiGiovanni Read The Full Question... while "which is better" may not have a single objective answer (as shown in the discussion you linked),"why did Cessna change their manual" reflects the fact that they did make that change. This question asks why that happened, and no amount of "I prefer to..." responses provides that answer, unless it's coming from someone who was involved in the decision. Ideally, an answer will be posted giving insight into Cessna's reasoning at that time.
